# Расширить уже заполненный значениями столбец VARCHAR2

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql-developer

Не влезает очередное значение. Пытаюсь расширить с 4000 до 6000 символов:

```
ALTER TABLE UPLOADFILE MODIFY CMD_TEXT VARCHAR2(6000 CHAR);
```

Ругается. Насколько я знаю, VARCHAR2 поддерживает до 32к символов. Как сделать чтобы было хорошо?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237463/what-is-the-max-size-of-varchar2-in-pl-sql-and-sql

Comment: Изменить тип на BLOB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Сделать чтобы было хорошо" можно на 12-м оракле.
До версии 11.2 включительно максимальный размер типа `VARCHAR2` был 4000 в SQL и 32767 в PL/SQL.

В 12-й версии можно установить параметр `MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED` (см. [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm#REFRN10321)), что даст возможность расширить тип `VARCHAR2` до 32767 байт.

Comment: Таки CLOB поставить пришлось ._.

Comment: А, ну да. С ним, правда, обычно возни чуть больше, поэтому я его не люблю, использую, только если надо файлы хранить в БД.